# Devise won't use my custom routes even though I can see them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

in my `routes.rb`:

```
  ## The Humen routes by Devise
  devise_for :humen, skip: [:sessions]
  as :humen do
    # sessions
    get '/login(.:format)' => 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_human_session
    post '/login(.:format)' => 'devise/sessions#create', as: :human_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_human_session
  end
```

However, upon going to `localhost:3000/login` I get:

```
Routing Error
Not Found
...
new_human_session_path  GET /login(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
human_session_path  POST    /login(.:format)    devise/sessions#create
destroy_human_session_path  DELETE  /logout(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
```

Which sucks. I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question was posted at the end of the `routes.rb` file, below `get ':username' => 'paywall#profile'` which meant that the `:username` route was being resolved before it got to `/login`

I moved the code to the top of the file and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change your devise routing code in your routes.rb file to something like below.

```
devise_scope :user do
    get '/login(.:format)' => 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_human_session
    post '/login(.:format)' => 'devise/sessions#create', as: :human_session

    get "logout", to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :logout

  end
```

Comment: `as` is an alias of `devise_scope`, as written here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes which makes both our code exactly the same. Only you called it the model `user`, while it is actually `human`